# Xamarin iOS deploy to apple store with missing icons error

Tags: xamarin

The error is look like this:
[missing icons error when uploading app to applestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRlcB.png)

I fixed this kind of issues by updating the Assets.xcassets before( just reassign the icon which reported with issues).
But today it doesn't work for all kinds of workaround.
My visual studio for mac version is: 8.9.10 (build 4)
Suspect it's a visual studio bug and waiting next release to see.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `ImageCropper.Forms` nuget or not ? Here is a known issue : https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/6095 .

Maybe you can try to create a new ImageAsset catalog and fill the image inside `AppIcons` ,then reselect it in info.plist.

---

Refer to

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/6095#issuecomment-550414189

Comment: Thanks. I'm using ImageCropper.Froms source code directly. And in the iOS project it has reference to ImageCropper.iOS project. But I have successfully released several versions to app store, it just suddenly doesn't work. I has tried to add a new ImageAsset 2 to my iOS project, and reselect all icons, and reset it in info.plist, but it seems doesn't work. Tomorrow I will try to remove the referece of ImageCropper.Forms project reference to do another try.

Comment: The best solution is that remove the nuget ImageCropper.Forms or try to search alternative for ImageCropper.Forms .

Comment: Yes, after removing ImageCropper.Forms from my iOS project reference then the publishing work succeed. But my app doesn't work any more. Need to find alternatives for it.

Comment: From the upper link I found this workaround and it works for me: 
1. First rebuild of your iOS project, the appstore will reject it with missing icons;
2. Then just modify the info.plist (eg: just increasing the build number), then build the ios project again( remember not rebuild, but just build)
3. publish again, apple store accept it.

Comment: Glad to hear the problem's been solved , if you have any other question feel free to let me know.